# How to resolve this error "Last Trap: Fast Data Access MMU Miss" when boot cdrom from Solaris ok mode?

Tags: boot, solaris, data-cd

I burned a new solaris 10 OS DVD with ultraISO, but this error was raised when boot cdrom from ok mode.

```
{0} ok boot cdrom -avs
Boot device: /pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0/disk@p6  File and args: -avs
-
ERROR: Last Trap: Fast Data Access MMU Miss
```

What does it mean? and How to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: The server information:  Netra SPARC T4-1, No Keyboard
Copyright (c) 1998, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
OpenBoot 4.38.8, 127.5000 GB memory available

Comment: Which version of Solaris 10?  Earlier versions of Solaris 10 may not run on a SPARC T4-1.

Comment: here is the solaris ios file name: SOL_10_0910_SPARC_SFPS14. So the version shall be 0910?

Answer (score 1):

The initial release of Solaris 10 9/10 is not supported on the SPARC T4-1 architecture. Per [the Oracle SPARC T4-1 data sheet](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/servers/sparc-enterprise/t-series/sparc-t4-1-ds-487858.pdf), the following operating systems versions are supported:

> **SOFTWARE**
>
> **Operating System**
>
> - Oracle Solaris 11.1 or later
> - Oracle Solaris 11 11/11
> - Oracle Solaris 10 1/13
> - Oracle Solaris 10 8/11
> - Support for Solaris 10 9/10 and    Solaris 10 10/09 + Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 patch set

Note that Solaris 10 9/10 and Solaris 10 10/09 both require the Solaris 10 8/11 patch set to run.

Answer (score 0):

Any known issues, recent patches, or recent firmware upgrade with the server?  Or are you trying to perform an initial install?

Have you tried just doing a `boot -s` or booting off different media?  Is the system able to boot normally (ie: to disk).

Have you tried running a post at max diags to see if that finds anything.  Past that, your best bet is to open a SR with Oracle.

Comment: Thanks. 
No firmware upgrade, and not an initial install, but a reinstall.
The system can be boot normally (ie: to disk)